# combine two foreach statements( image& text)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a "foreach" statement to fetch all images from a folder to print on webpage.

I also need to give  'links' to these images.

Links are saved in database table called 'advertisement'.

I fetched all images and displayed correctly.

but I can't make these images as links.

I also used another "foreach" statement to fetch  'link' rows from table 'advertisement' table.

but how to combine these two.

Comment: Please provide some code, as it is now it's hard to figure your exact code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
$files = array('1.jpg','2.jpg');
$stm = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM advertisement');
$linkInfo = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$outputArray = array();
foreach( $linkInfo as $row )
{
    if( in_array($row['file'], $files) )
    {
        $outputArray['file'] = $row['link'];
    }
}

foreach( $outputArray as $file => $link )
{
    echo "<a href='".$link."'><img src='". $file ."'></a>";
}
```

Not sure how your structure is, but say you have a table like this:

```
------------------------------
| file        | link         |
------------------------------
| 1.jpg       | http://...   |
+
+
+
```

This should work, with some adjustment according to your own structure.